# Characteristic functional of Brownian motion

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to find the characteristic functional of a Brownian motion $W_t$, defined to be

$L(\phi)=E(exp(i \int_{R} \phi W_t dt))$

for compactly supported smooth $\phi$.  In order to find out what $L$ is I thought about expanding the exponential term to get $e^{i\phi \int W}=1+i \phi \int W + (i \phi \int W )^2/2 + \cdots$

and then try to find some dense set of $\phi$ that makes the sum easily calculable after taking the integral with respect to $dP$ but I think this method is a little too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X=\int_R \phi (t)W_t dt$ is normally distributed. To find its characteristic function all to have to do is to find the mean and variance. The mean is $0$ and $EX^{2}= \int_R \int_R  \phi(t)\phi (s) EW_tW_sdtds$. Use the fact that $EW_tW_s=t\wedge s$.

Comment: How is $X$ normally distributed when $\phi$ is an arbitrary smooth function?

Comment: Write the integral as  a limit of Riemann sums. Linear combinations of jointly normal r.v.'s is normal ans a.s. limits of normal r.v.'s is normal. @LiterallyanOrange